# Unable to Connect to a service using Ingress Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am very much new to Docker and Kubernetes. While learning Kubernetes I come to a point where I am working with [Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/).

Let me share my Service and My Ingress controller YML file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: simptekapi-api-service
spec:
  selector:
    component: api
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
  name: docker-registry
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: simptek.api
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: simptekapi-api-service
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /
```

The problem is I am unable to connect to my service from Bowser/Postman/Curl using My minikube Ip. or Host.

[image]

So I thought there might be some issue with my service. So tried to stick with Nodeport. But NodePort works just fine. So my Sevice is also fine.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: simptekapi-api-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    component: api
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 30007
```

[image]

I have also added `172.17.245.221 simptek.api` to my host file.

I am actually unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. I have tried to change my Ingress file several ways. Below.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
  name: docker-registry
spec:
  rules:
  - host: simptek.api
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: simptekapi-api-service
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /
```

also tried with adding `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` to ingress.

I am sharing my logs which might be helpful for anybody who wants to help me.

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system

NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-66bff467f8-5dv28                    1/1     Running     6          7d1h
coredns-66bff467f8-w72dg                    1/1     Running     6          7d1h
etcd-minikube                               1/1     Running     0          36h
ingress-nginx-admission-create-94wpw        0/1     Completed   0          30h 
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-p5ffx         0/1     Completed   0          30h
ingress-nginx-controller-7bb4c67d67-jfdrm   1/1     Running     0          30h
kube-apiserver-minikube                     1/1     Running     0          36h
kube-controller-manager-minikube            1/1     Running     18         7d1h
kube-proxy-d5bvb                            1/1     Running     6          7d1h
kube-scheduler-minikube                     1/1     Running     17         7d1h
storage-provisioner                         1/1     Running     11         7d1h

kubectl get ing

NAME              CLASS    HOSTS         ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
docker-registry   <none>   simptek.api   172.17.245.221   80      53m

kubectl describe ing docker-registry

Name:             docker-registry
Namespace:        default
Address:          172.17.245.221
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
Host         Path  Backends
----         ----  --------
simptek.api
           /   simptekapi-api-service:5000 (172.17.0.10:5000,172.17.0.6:5000,172.17.0.7:5000)
Annotations:   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 0
           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: 600
           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: 600
Events:
Type    Reason  Age                    From                      Message
----    ------  ----                   ----                      -------
Normal  CREATE  54m                    nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/docker-registry
Normal  CREATE  54m                    nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/docker-registry
Normal  UPDATE  3m58s (x100 over 53m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/docker-registry
Normal  UPDATE  3m58s (x100 over 53m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/docker-registry

kubectl get namespaces

NAME                   STATUS   AGE
default                Active   7d1h
ingress-nginx          Active   30h
kube-node-lease        Active   7d1h
kube-public            Active   7d1h
kube-system            Active   7d1h
kubernetes-dashboard   Active   7d1h
```

It would be a great help if anybody can guide me about my wrongdoings. Please Let me know any more information needed.

Comment: Can you share how your Nginx Ingress controller **service** is configured?

Comment: @EduardoBaitello do you want me to share the pod behind the Service, which I am targeting now?

Comment: No, I mean the configuration used for your ingress service. You are supposed to access your application through the Nginx Ingress (`ingress service --> ingress container --> (evaluate ingress rule) --> app-service --> app-container`). How are you exposing your ingress service?

Comment: @EduardoBaitello I actually use https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml this for ingress- containers

Comment: @EduardoBaitello I only configured Ingtress-service which I have shared in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the below annotation from Ingress

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
```

Comment: @OhHiMark Yes, I have solved it, I was missing some steps.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing some steps. I am answering the question. Anyone who will face a similar issue might be helpful.

- First of all whether for Mac/Windows individuals have to perform `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml` (Missing in the documentaion)
- Then don't forget to perform `minikube addons enable ingress` (What I have missed)
- Also Don't forget to use `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` in `annotations` section
- If you dont require a url rewrite then dont use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`
- still facing the issue then Try below one

  ```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: ingress-service
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  spec:
    rules:
      - http:
          paths:
            - path: /?(.*)
              backend:
                serviceName: service1
                servicePort: 3000
            - path: /api/?(.*)
              backend:
                serviceName: service2
                servicePort: 5000
  ```